# Position object in front of camera in RealityKit

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I want to position an object in front of the camera, without changing its parent. The object should be in the center of the screen, at specified distance `distanceFromCamera`.

The object is stored as `cursorEntity` and is a child of `sceneEntity`.

A reference to the ARView is stored as `arView` and the position of the `cursorEntity` gets updated in the function `updateCursorPosition`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, add `forward` in an extension to float4x4 that gives the forward-facing directional vector of a transform matrix.

```swift
extension float4x4 {
    var forward: SIMD3<Float> {
        normalize(SIMD3<Float>(-columns.2.x, -columns.2.y, -columns.2.z))
    }
}
```

Then, implement the following 4 steps:

```swift
func updateCursorPosition() {

    let cameraTransform: Transform = arView.cameraTransform

    // 1. Calculate the local camera position, relative to the sceneEntity
    let localCameraPosition: SIMD3<Float> = sceneEntity.convert(position: cameraTransform.translation, from: nil)

    // 2. Get the forward-facing directional vector of the camera using the extension described above
    let cameraForwardVector: SIMD3<Float> = cameraTransform.matrix.forward

    // 3. Calculate the final local position of the cursor using distanceFromCamera
    let finalPosition: SIMD3<Float> = localCameraPosition + cameraForwardVector * distanceFromCamera
    
    // 4. Apply the translation
    cursorEntity.transform.translation = finalPosition

}
```